# Why is https//www.google.com/ getting redirected to http://www.https.com/www.google.com

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, domain, https

Every https domain name when entered without ":" is getting redirected to www.https.com. Why?

Try this
https//www.stackoverflow.com/
https//www.facebook.com
https//www.google.com

PS: www.https.com is pointing to http://www.homeimprovement.com/

Comment: Well actually, when you miss a : the dns server of your provider can't resolve the url and you get redirected to a site defined by your provider.

Comment: Are you getting the same redirect to homeimprovement.com ?

Comment: Nope, this should differ from provider to provider.

Answer (score 4):

You need the `:` otherwise your browser will do funny things.  It may think you forgot to enter the `.com` part of a URL, or it might submit the words to a search engine.

The basic format of a URL is as follows:

`{protocol}://{address}`

and you need the colon in there for it to be a standard URL.

Comment: I tried wget with the same url. It is also forwarding the domain to the same address.

Comment: If you didn't specify the colon with wget either, that's not surprising.  *You need the colon.*

Answer (score 3):

Well if you don't put in the " : " then you aren't fully qualifying the address and because of this your web browser has to take it's best guess.

```
(protocol)://(prefix).(domain)
```

All websites follow the same order as above. All of which needs to be completed for the address to be found correctly.

otherwise google etc will have to guess what you're trying to reach.

Answer (score 0):

As addition to the above answers.

It depends perhaps also on the browser you use, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Edge, Opera, and so on. They have commonly a feature activiated or not "autocomplete url" or some [add on's](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/url-fixer/) , but it might be also a problem with the hostfile or dns of provider.

Cheking the host files:

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts  (newer windows)
>
> etc/hosts (linux)

Someone tried to [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241512/how-does-chrome-update-url-bar-completions) how autocompletes works in Chrome Browser.